# Verify data from PHP file with get method (AJAX)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, if-statement

I want to use an if statement to compare data from a PHP file.

I'm using AJAX to get the data from PHP files and append them to HTML.

This will be an example of code.

**PHP_file.php**

```
if ($active == "ready") {
   echo "true";
} else {
   echo "false";
}
```

**AJAX Function**

```
$.get("PHP_file.php", function(data, status){
  if (status == "success"){
    if (data == "true") {
      //do something
    } else{
      //do something else
    };
  }
});
```

The AJAX function doesn't do what I want, it always ends up in the "else" statement. Can I read the data, and compare it, with jQuery?

**UPDATE** [**SOLVED**]
I found the problem: some functions we're working properly so it was always going to the else statement.

Thank you for the help everyone, and sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The `if (status == "success")` in the callback is redundant, as the logic in that function will only be executed if a successful status code was returned. Other than that your code seems fine. What's the issue you have?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan about the status part, if the status is "fail", it won't stop the flow of the code? I mean, the returns an error, or something?
Somehow the data is ends up always on the else statement

Comment: Check what the value of `status` is by doing `console.log(status)`. If the AJAX request fails then your handler function won't be called at all

Comment: @MarianaLeites clarifications to the question should be in the text of the question. [Edit] your question and make it clear what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: Agreed with @RoryMcCrossan in that the check for `status` is not needed but the rest of your JS looks OK. Are you sure the PHP file is returning `'true'`? Try `$.get("PHP_file.php", function(data) { console.log(data); });`

Comment: I guess I found the problem: some functions we're working properly so it was going to the else statement